# advantages of a 2 stack PDA and a multitape Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, pushdown-automaton

What are the advantages of a 2 stack PDA and a multitape Turing Machine?

2 stack:
   Can work like a Turing Machine using one stack as the left tape and one as the right
   Can take context sensetive data

2 Tape:
   Seperates the input and the computation

Anymore?

Answer (score 2):

A 2 stack PDA can not only work like a Turing machine, it is functionally equivalent to a Turing machine. [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2833) answer on the CS stack exchange goes into further detail .

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine) wikipedia article explains that a multitape Turing machine can always be represented by a single tape Turing machine, and therefore cannot compute anything a single tape Turing machine cannot. There can be an advantage to having multiple tapes in that the multitape machine will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Pair pieces of this answer,

Firstly, the class of languages acknowledged by Turing Machines is not context sensitive, it's recursively enumerable (context sensitive is the class of languages you get from directly made automata).

The second part, considering we adjust the question, is that yes, a two-stack PDA is as robust as a TM. It's mildly simpler to believe that we're using the model of TMs that has a tape that's incessant in one direction only (though both directions are not much harder, and equivalent).

To see the equality, just think of the first stack as the contents of the tape to the left of the popular position, and the second as the contents to the right. Start by pushing the normal "bottom of stack" markers on both stacks, then we can simulate the TM by popping from the right stack and pushing to the left to move right, and vice versa to move left. If we hit the bottom of the left stack we behave accordingly (halt and reject, or stay where you, depending on the model), if we hit the bottom of the right stack, we just push a blank symbol onto the left.

The relationship the other way should be even more obvious, i.e. that we can simulate a two-stack PDA with a TM.

and you can say that, `Turing machine tape is infinite in one direction, extending indefinitely to the right. We use one stack to represent the tape content on the finite portion of the tape to the left of the head and another to represent the content of the finite non-blank portion of the tape to the right of the head. The two-stack PDA resembles a move of the TM by suitably pushing and leaping the two stacks`.